# AngularJS Remove old $watchers when re-compiling dynamic html

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have an AngularJS application that used to Build Pages dynamically (retrieve an XML from Server and by reading that XML building pages or forms) for an XML we have to build few pages all are related with each other and can be negative via 'Next' , 'Previous' buttons.

to implement that we have something like,

```
<div>
   <form name="myController.mainForm" novalidate>
      <div my-dynamic="myController.dynamicHtml"></div>
   </form>
</div>
```

herer myDynamic is directive, which deals with generated html and when we have to navigate to another page we generate new HTML for that page and assign it to`myController.dynamicHtml`

and in that Directive I have something like this,

```
link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.myDynamic, function (html) {
        element.html(html);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    });
}
```

Now in each page I have number of input controls(or directives), and each have few bindings that that adds to number of watchers.

I have notice that if I <del>negative</del> navigate, to another page, watchers on previous pages not getting destroyed, until my-dynamic directive gets removed from scope.

What I need to do to make sure that watches on previous page gets destroyed when we again compile the HTML.

Comment: Everytime the `$compile` service links something to a scope, it adds watchers. That is why directives such as `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes. They link to the child scope and destroy that scope when destroying the compiled DOM. Use [scope.$new](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$new) and [scope.$destroy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy).

Comment: can you explain in details, I am not sure how we can use scope.$new in our case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everytime the `$compile` service links something to a scope, it adds watchers. That is why directives such as `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes. They link to the child scope and destroy that scope when destroying the compiled DOM. Use [scope.$new](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$new) and [scope.$destroy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy).

```
link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
    var newScope;
    scope.$watch(attrs.myDynamic, function (html) {
        if (newScope) {
            newScope.$destroy();
        };
        element.empty();
        if (html) {
            element.html(html);
            newScope = scope.$new()
            $compile(element.contents())(newScope);
        };
    });
}
```

This creates and destroys a child scope on changes.

Comment: This solution is not praised enough! Fantastic. I would hope this knowledge is more widespread.

Answer (score 1):

You can unwatch anything by assigning a variable to the watch:

```
var dynamicWatcher = scope.$watch(attrs.myDynamic, function (html) {
    element.html(html);
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);

    dynamicWatcher(); // unwatch
});
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) at the return type:

> Returns
>   function()
>   Returns a deregistration function for this listener.

Comment: thanks for looking into it, but if we un-watch inside $watch function, it will remove the watchers that current page needs.